# My reputation page gives a 500 error

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, error-message

I'm not sure why, but yesterday my reputation page stopped working (only affects SO, other SE rep pages are unaffected)

https://stackoverflow.com/users/2370483/machavity?tab=reputation

Attempting to go there, even in a private window (not logged in and no cache) gives it. I had someone in chat try and they got a 500 as well. It's not a network-wide problem either (here's a [different user that works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4342498/nathanoliver?tab=reputation))

Comment: Looks like you broke the rep cap

Comment: Let's all flood their error logs with this. That'll show 'em.

Comment: @BoltClock done ...

Comment: @NathanOliver I bet this never happens to Jon Skeet

Comment: I'm not seeing a 500 error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should be fixed. Nick went poking at it and accidentally fixed it while debugging. We're not sure of the cause but will keep an eye out for any other occurrences.

Comment: Debugging 101: Poke it with a stick.